# Light turning on and off

Tags: modifiers, light

I'm trying to make a little scene with a light turning off and on randomly, I tried adding a keyframe to the light power and applying a noise modifier. However the result is too "soft", I mean the light just get a little dimmer or brighter. I'd like to know if there was a way to make the light just turning off and on randomly without having to manually add keyframe through the whole timeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the noise modifier set up, as you already do.  now add a **limits** modifiers.  there are four checkboxes.  Check **Maximum Y**, and **Minimum Y**, and set the maximum value to the maximum strength you want for your light, and set the minimum value to the minimum strength you want for you light.  The animation will still look to smooth, so crank the **strength** value of your noise modifier until you get a curve that looks more binary.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: wops, sorry, I saw your answer too late. If it's ok I'll leave mine up to keep the gif

Comment: That's fine. :)  The gif is really helpful.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it works great ! I'm fairly new to Blender so I think i'll stick to the simple modifiers and leave nodes for later because it kinda looks terrifying right now haha

Comment: yeah, nodes are kind of intimidating at first. :)  For simple materials, you can just add a principled shader node, and adjust the roughness, color, and metallic settings.  (metallic should be either 0, or 1. if you are making something metal, it should be one.  if not, it should be 0.

Comment: Yes, nodes are powerful but quite intimidating. If you plan on using Blender a lot you need to learn how to use them (they are not that difficult, but you need to spend some time on them), but for now the modifiers are a very good option, and the fact you can see the fcurve shape is a very good thing too

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on where to get information on nodes ? I have a hard time finding any info on how to get started with them.

Comment: Blender Guru's famous beginner donut tutorial has a section on material nodes.  It's only fault is that it doesn't use the principled shader (it hadn't been developed yet,) but it does give you a good starting point.

Comment: yes, you can watch some tutorials on youtube (like his one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETMoOhAgXiY), but the best way to learn them is just to use them. 

Enable the **Wrangler Node** addon, so that you can press Ctrl+Shift+LMB and see the output of every node. This way you'll see what each node do and you will be able to mix them to get the final result

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **Noise Modifier**: just increase a lot the strenght of the noise and the add a **Limits Modifier**, to clip the values between 0 and your maximum desired value

[image]

This is the quick and easy way. If you want more control you could use nodes (I am thinking of a noise modifier applied to the value of the strenght of the an *Emission* shader, using *Greater Than* and *Less Than* nodes), but you would need to use a mesh instead of a light object